# Vector3.MoveTowards() not working due to animation

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've got an animation that moves a character in a patrol route. Very simple pingpong pattern on the X axis.

[image: Move animation]

Then I have some code that is supposed to make the character (a boar) chase the player:

```
    private void MoveTowardsPlayer() {
      var step =  speed * Time.deltaTime;
      transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, prey.position, step);
    }
```

This code is called on `Update()` when a boolean is set:

```
    private void Update() {        
    if (canChase) {
        Debug.Log("Moving towards player");
        MoveTowardsPlayer();   
    }
}
```

When that bool is set, the animation to move the player is set to false, I transition to the `Idle` animation (so the patrol stops).

Yet, because of that animation, I cannot make the boar move towards the player. Not sure why.

If I disable all animations then the boar moves.

But I can't disable all animations, I need some of them.

And Unity doesn't seem to have a method to disable a single animation.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Animator always overrules whatever you do in script because it is one of the last things that is applied before rendering. As soon as you have any animatioclip with a key frame on a property the animator takes hold of it .. you could nest your object with the animations under a movement root and move that one instead .. or go for [Root Motion](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RootMotion.html) and rather pass in the speed as parameter to the animator as well

Comment: @derHugo Thanks I tried the Root Motion but then it still fights agains the animation :(

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you **add** to your object a **parent transform** and move towards the parent transform.
If the animator has the key to any element of a component the component becomes uneditable via code.
There are a lot of other solutions for this, but adding a parent **and moving it, not the child**, will be a good solution.